# Python/Regex can't find phrase or value even though it's plain as day in text

Tags: python, regex

Here is the text when I print to the console:

```
Equities
  Purchases
503,773.09
3,900,439.7
  Sales Cost Removed
(397,196.15)
(3,835,270.54)
  Other
-
(2,452.33)
Tax Exempt Securities
  Purchases
301,596.54
606,468.27
  Sales Cost Removed
(350,825.56)
(688,845.64)
  Other
1,268.59
2,000.26
Fixed Income
  Other
-
-
```

- I'm trying to pull the value after "Tax Exempt Securities", then after "Sales Cost Removed".
- In other instances of this data, "Sales Cost Removed" isn't present under the "Tax Exempt Securities" header, so I want to pull the value ONLY IF it appears before reading the phrase "Fixed Income", as that has it's own line items that includes the term "Sales Cost Removed".
- I've tried the following regex pattern:
  `pattern_1 = re.compile(r"Tax Exempt Securities[\s\S]((?!Fixed Income).)*?Sales Cost Removed[\s\S]*?(\d[\d,]*\.?\d*)")`
- It works when I'm searching for "Purchases" under Tax Exempt Securities just fine, but won't work when searching for "Sales Cost Removed" or "Other".
- Here is the rest of the code to give you a better idea of what I'm trying to accomplish:

```
for page_num in range(len(pdf_reader.pages)):
    page = pdf_reader.pages[page_num]
    text = page.extract_text()
    print(text)
    print(f"Searching in page {page_num+1}...")
    matches = pattern_1.findall(text)
    if matches:
        print(f"Matches found: {matches}")
        value_to_write = matches[0][1].replace(',', '')
        print(value_to_write)
        try:
            value_to_write = float(value_to_write)
            print(f"Value to write: {value_to_write}")
        except ValueError:
            print("Conversion to float failed, setting value to 0")
            value_to_write = 0
        break
    else:
        print("No match found on this page.")`
```

I've tried different combinations of regex, and can't seem to find the right combination to find the value I'm looking for.

Comment: You could for example not cross matching all the mentioned lines in the question, see https://regex101.com/r/eJKTol/1

Comment: You need the single line flag so that `.` matches newlines

Comment: Using regex for this seems kind of crazy anyway.

Comment: @tripleee what do you suggest on making this more efficient?  I'm just starting, and regex just made sense.  I'm using it on investment statements we get monthly so that it looks for the same patterns and pulls the values so we can import changes as a journal entry.

Comment: while it might take part in a solution, a regex is going to be painful here, while you could parse the input by-lines with the rules you have!

Answer (score 0):

Try the following *capture pattern*.

```
(?sm)^Tax Exempt Securities.+?^  Sales Cost Removed.+?\(?(.+?)\)?$.+?Fixed Income
```

- `(?sm)`, toggle-on *"single-line"*, and *"multi-line"*, mode.
- `^Tax Exempt Securities`, static text, at the start of a line, `^`
- `.+?^  Sales Cost Removed`, all characters up to the static text, at the start of a line
- `.+?\(?`, all characters up to an optional `(`
- `(.+?)\)?$`, capture all characters up to, an optional `)`, or the end of the line, `$`
- `.+?Fixed Income`, all characters up to the static text

Here is an example.

```py
p = r'(?sm)^Tax Exempt Securities.+?^  Sales Cost Removed.+?\(?(.+?)\)?$.+?Fixed Income'
m = re.search(p, s)
if m: print(m.group(1))
```

Output

```
350,825.56
```